# How to align-text left for radio button and checkboxes, after centering everything

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox

I have 2 questions really. How can I align my radio buttons and checkboxes to the left of my already centered form-group in css.They are currently all center, but I want the checkboxes and radio buttons to be aligned to the left, but still in center. Also how can I make my form take up the whole page with a scroll bar like the example I will provide. everything current just sits at the top of page. Please let me know of any questions, really am stuck here and just need a little nudge. Thanks.
Example: https://survey-form.freecodecamp.rocks/

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-group {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.clue {
  text-align: center;
}

.input-checkboxes {
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: lato, arial;
}

body {
  background: url(images/tech2.webp);
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  grid-column: 5 / 9;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto 20px;
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.763);
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.checkbox,
.radio-button {
  display: block;
}

.form-grou>.inline {
  margin-right: 6px;
  text-align: left;
}

#submit {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #2f80ed;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 24px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    grid-column: 1 / 12;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1 id="title" class="text-center">Survey Form</h1>
  <p id="description" class="description text-center">Thank you for taking the time to help me improve my skills as a developer</p>
</header>

<div class="container">

  <form id="survey-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="name-label" for="name">Name: 
          <input 
          required 
          id="name" 
          for="name"
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Name"></label><br/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="email-label" for="email">Email: 
        <input 
        required 
        id="email" 
        type="email" 
        placeholder="E-mail"></label><br/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="number-label" for="numebr">Age: 
        <input 
        required 
        id="number" 
        min="13" 
        max="120" type="number"
        placeholder="Age"></label><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Which option best describes your current role?</p>
      <select for="dropdown" id="dropdown" name="role" class="form-control" required>
        <option disabled selected>Seelct current role</option>
        <option value="student">Student</option>
        <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
        <option value="job">Full time job coding</option>
        <option value="preferNo">Prefer not to say</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>


      </select><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Based on my portfolio/resume, would you say that I am job ready?<br/>
        <input 
        type="radio" 
        name="referal" 
        class="inline" 
        value="definitely" /> Definitely</label><br/>
      <label>
          <input 
          type="radio" 
          name="referal" 
          class="inline" 
          value="maybe" /> Maybe</label><br/>
      <label>
          <input 
          type="radio" 
          name="referal" 
          class="inline" 
          value="definitelyNot"/> Definitely not
              </label><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

      <label>In your opinion, what would you say is my strongest skill?<br/>
      <select id="improved" name="improved" class="form-control" required>
          <option disabled selected>Seelct an option</option>
          <option value="html/css">HTML/CSS</option>
          <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
          <option value="ui/ux">UI/UX Design</option>
          <option value="response">Responsiveness/Functionability</option>
          <option>Project Ideas</option>

      </select><br/>
      
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

      <p>What would you like to see improved? <span class="clue">(Check all that apply)</span></p>
      <label>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox" 
          value="frontend"/> Front-End skills<br/>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox"
          value="backend" /> Back-End skills<br/>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox"
          value="ui/ux"/> UI/UX Design<br/>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox"
          value="response"/> Responsiveness/Functionality<br/>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox"
          value="response" /> Project Ideas<br/>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox" 
          value="number"/> Number of Projects<br/>

              </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Any other comments or suggestions?</p>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="3" cols="30" class="input-textarea" placeholder="Enter your comments here..."></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">Submit
      </button>
    </div>

</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please ask just one question per post. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What do you mean "take up the whole page"? Your example has larger inputs and space between. Did you use your browser to inspect the elements there? It's all fairly apparent if you look at the example more closely.

Comment: you have , in my opinion, too much HTML levels (input + labels + p and eventually fieldser would do the job). You also have a wrong structure, if label can hold an input, it cannot hold many ... . Finally, with a simple structure and a grid display, you could easily do manage your form.

Answer (score 1):

You gave the div with the radio buttons the class `.form-group.` This class has a property `align-center` if you remove that from the div the buttons will align to the left.

If you give the `.text-center` to the `<p>` the tekst will align center

```css
.text-center{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.form-group{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    
}


    

.clue{
    text-align: center;
}

.input-checkboxes{
    text-align: center;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: lato, arial;}

body{
    background: url(images/tech2.webp);
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container{
    grid-column: 5 / 9;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.763);
    
}
header{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
h1{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.checkbox, .radio-button {
    display: block;
}
.form-grou > .inline {
    margin-right: 6px;
    text-align: left;
}


#submit {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #2f80ed;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px 24px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .container {
        grid-column: 1 / 12;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Survey</title>

    
  </head>
  
  <header class="header">
    <h1 id="title" class="text-center">Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description" class="description text-center">Thank you for taking the time to help me improve my skills as a developer</p>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
    
    <form id="survey-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="name-label" for="name">Name: 
          <input 
          required 
          id="name" 
          for="name"
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Name"></label><br/>
          </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label id="email-label" for="email">Email: 
        <input 
        required 
        id="email" 
        type="email" 
        placeholder="E-mail"></label><br/>
        </div>
        
      <div class="form-group">
      <label id="number-label" for="numebr">Age: 
        <input 
        required 
        id="number" 
        min="13" 
        max="120" type="number"
        placeholder="Age"></label><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <p>Which option best describes your current role?</p>
      <select for="dropdown" id="dropdown" name="role" class="form-control" required>
          <option disabled selected>Seelct current role</option>
          <option value="student">Student</option>
          <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
          <option value="job">Full time job coding</option>
          <option value="preferNo">Prefer not to say</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
         

      </select><br/>
      </div>
      <div>
      <label>  <p class="text-center">Based on my portfolio/resume, would you say that I am job ready?<br/> </p>
        <input 
        type="radio" 
        name="referal" 
        class="inline" 
        value="definitely" /> Definitely</label><br/>
        <label>
          <input 
          type="radio" 
          name="referal" 
          class="inline" 
          value="maybe" /> Maybe</label><br/>
        <label>
          <input 
          type="radio" 
          name="referal" 
          class="inline" 
          value="definitelyNot"/> Definitely not
              </label><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

        <label>In your opinion, what would you say is my strongest skill?<br/>
      <select id="improved" name="improved" class="form-control" required>
          <option disabled selected>Seelct an option</option>
          <option value="html/css">HTML/CSS</option>
          <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
          <option value="ui/ux">UI/UX Design</option>
          <option value="response">Responsiveness/Functionability</option>
          <option>Project Ideas</option>

      </select><br/>
      
      </label>
      </div>
      <div>

      <p class="text-center" >What would you like to see improved? <span class="clue">(Check all that apply)</span></p>
        <label>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox" 
          value="frontend"/> Front-End skills<br/>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox"
          value="backend" /> Back-End skills<br/>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox"
          value="ui/ux"/> UI/UX Design<br/>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox"
          value="response"/> Responsiveness/Functionality<br/>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox"
          value="response" /> Project Ideas<br/>
          <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name="improved" 
          class="input-checkbox" 
          value="number"/> Number of Projects<br/>

              </label>
        
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <p>Any other comments or suggestions?</p>
          <textarea 
          name="comments" 
          id="comments"
          rows="3" 
          cols="30" 
          class="input-textarea"
          placeholder="Enter your comments here..."></textarea>
              </div>
     
      <div class="form-group">
      <button 
      type="submit" 
      id="submit" 
      class="submit-button">Submit
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the css of .text-center and .form-group

Comment: https://codepen.io/shubhanshu2000/pen/VwXXEwr visit the codepen